# Subtraction method in two colums using php

Tags: php

I am using subtraction method and then I am reducing selected value from q1(20) and q2(30). I have selected check box with 25 value. Now q1(20)-25 ,result= -5 value is coming but I don't want negative value I can take 5 points from q2 and after calculation value of q2 will come 25. I am sorry for my bad communication
 please suggest me

```
q1      |      q2

20             30
```

Comment: if you want only 5 not -5 you can use abs() function

Comment: You want all negatives to be positives?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the question.

If your problem is the negative use [abs](http://php.net/manual/es/function.abs.php) function

abs(-5) = 5
abs(5) = 5

Answer (score 0):

if you want only 5 not -5 you can use abs() function

```
$q1 = 20;
$q2 = 30;
$result = abs($q2 - $q1);
echo $result;
```